# Efficient persistent storage for lists in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, persistent-storage

I have a (key, value) map where for each key I have a somewhat large list of heterogeneous lists (~max about 250 items). Each list is a mix of strings and numbers that I might want to iterate over. The key is a string. If I wanted to store such a list with thousands of such (key, value) pairs persistently for efficient retrieval what are the best options? If I use sqlite then I would need to create a table for each key and then map the lists to individual records in the database. Are there better and efficient options if the goal is fast retrieval of the list of lists for a particular key?
Here is a short example. Say animals is a map of keys to list of lists. Sample data looks like this:

```
 animals = { 
    "Lion" : [["Siberian", 203, "Tanzania", 123.56], ["Russian", 321, "Timbktu", 23423.2]],
    "Tiger: [["White", 121, "Australia", 1211.1], ["Indian", 111, "India", 1241.5]]
  }
```

So I want to be able to persist this data structure and be able to quickly index by the name of an animal (always unique) and get the list of lists for the particular animal I care about. If the lists within each animal's info is of fixed length and fixed fields, can I exploit that feature somehow to improve efficiency?

Comment: Thanks, just looked pickle up.  Can I have one single pickle of (key1, [[], []....., []]), (key2, [[], [] ..., []] and so on and then be able to retrieve an arbitrary record indexed by key efficiently?

Comment: Do you want easy access to the raw data outside python? If it's stored in files, should they be human readable or you don't care.

Comment: I want to be able to access it from Python primarily. I will assume for now that that's all I care about. I am also updating my question to have a short example to illustrate what I want.

Comment: Which of the [CRUD operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) are most important to you?

Comment: Read and Update. The initial creation can take some time but incremental updates need to be fast and read needs to be really fast.

Comment: actually I think the single most important is R. I can live with a slower CUD

Answer (score 2):

As Blender states in the comment, pickle is a reasonable choice. Make sure not to use the original version, though, and instead use the C-based [`cPickle`](http://pymotw.com/2/pickle/). Alternatively, consider [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest one of the fast JSON libraries. There are several speed comparisons online that suggest that JSON can be as fast or rather faster than `pickle`. Check this one for example: 
http://lvsl.github.io/2011/12/28/python-serialization-benchmark.html
and 
https://blog.hartleybrody.com/python-serialize/

There are several JSON serialization alternatives, and again, there are some comparisons online, e.g. 
https://medium.com/@jyotiska/json-vs-simplejson-vs-ujson-a115a63a9e26

I would suggest looking into `ujson`, which seems to be really fast and has one big advantage over e.g. `pickle`, it's very easy to inspect the data as they are saved in a human readable format. On the other hand `pickle` will be a bit easier to use with custom types, although you can still define custom encoders for custom types for JSON. Overall, choose JSON if you care more about human readability, and pickle if what really matters is having a few lines of code less for custom types.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestions, its a good start. I realized I might have another requirement.. which is to fetch a record and then update it and write it back. Do most of these tools allow that kind of selective updating?

Comment: For reading/writing one file, JSON's potential speedup (which is on the order of microseconds, even for a large and complex object) doesn't make a difference. Why lose the ability to use complex data structures like classes and tuples when there's no benefit to doing so?

Comment: Also that article doesn't test the different modules property (using `pickle.dump` instead of `pickle.dumps`, not using `pickle`'s `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`, using only one really tiny object, not testing loading performance, etc.), so its results aren't very useful.

Comment: The OP's example mentioned only types that are easily serializable using JSON, so I wouldn't call that a problem here. Additionally, it's no big deal to define your own encoders for custom types anyways.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't consider those articles supper accurate benchmarks indeed, but they do show that JSON can be pretty fast. So, it's all a matter of requirements. I do like to be able to inspect my data easily and for instance use files as a way to move my data across programming environments, e.g. Python/Matlab

Comment: Another intersting benchmark http://lvsl.github.io/2011/12/28/python-serialization-benchmark.html which shows that cpickle although a tiny bit faster than ujson, doesn't really give that much of an advantage. So, I would still say, choose JSON if you care more about human readability, and pickle if what really matters is having a few lines of code less for custom types.

Comment: I am using cpickle right now and it is working reasonably well although the number of records are only in the thousands for me so its not too much data. I might do some benchmarking for my specific case and see whether JSON is better.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you may want to consider [REDIS](http://redis.io) which is an excellent key:value database solution.  This [tutorial](http://openmymind.net/2011/11/8/Redis-Zero-To-Master-In-30-Minutes-Part-1/) provides a relatively quick introduction.